# Ambient Occlusion Solid Mode and Edit Mode

Tags: modeling

enter image description here

[image: 2.79a]

Is there a way to bring back the 2.79 ambient occlusion in modeling, in 2.82a?

Answer (score 4):

The closest thing that exists in 2.8x that I know of is the cavity setting, in the viewport shading settings.

[image: Cavity settings]

The "Valley" setting is the closest thing to the old "Strength" setting from 2.79b that I can find. Here is a comparison of the 2.79 viewport with AO enabled and the 2.8 viewport with Cavity Type: World enabled.

[image: 2.79]

[image: 2.8]

Hope this helps!

Comment: I know cavity, but It is just doesn't feel right If you know what I mean. But if you said so maybe I'll try to move on and try something new. Thank you!

Comment: @kuromajin Sorry I couldn't be more help! Good luck!